# How to throw silent exception in c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a property bound to ComboBox

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Kind, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
```

and in the property setter I throw an exception in some business circumstances to abort setting the property.

```
    public MyKind Kind
    {
        get { return kind; }
        set 
        {
            if (kind != value)
            {
                if (SomeRuleFailed(value))
                throw new Exception("to be ate by binding code");
                kind = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

It works smooth except the fact that VS2010 pops up every time I raise exception. Is there any kind of exception to raise or attribute to be set so debugger left in background?

Comment: WPF has built in interfaces to handle object property validation, that I'd encourage you to have a look at

Comment: I do use IDataErrorInfo as well as IDataNotifyErrorInfo for plain forms. This case has some popup involved that forced me to folow exception way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be throwing an instance of an `Exception` class. You should throw an instance of a class derived from `Exception`.

You can create your own exception class (and you should out of habit if you have something that's not already covered by the framework) then you can select the exceptions you want Visual Studio to break on.

Once you've created your exception class, go to Debug-->Exceptions... and then pick the exceptions you want to have the debugger break on.

Comment: I don't like to create exception class just to communicate with studio and I reused  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException

Comment: Why are you "Just communicating with [Visual] studio"? Surely you are getting some other benefit out of throwing an exception? If so, you should either be using an existing type (excluding Exception itself because it is too general) or creating a specific type for your application scenario.

Comment: The only benefit is to abort binding, no more usage of this exception. Delphi language has AbortException that ignored by debugger and I was looking for something similar in c#, without setup of all team computers to ignore specific exception. unfortunately, no marvel bullet in .net.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the kinds of exceptions that cause the debugger to break by going to **Debug > Exceptions**. Untick the **Thrown** checkbox against **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** or pick your exception types individually.

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl-Alt-E in Visual Studio to open the Exception configuration for the Debugger, and select or unselect what you need.